# Bash: call make when directory changes

Tags: bash

I usually like to use `entr` when developing on my own hardware to run commands when a directory changes.

However, sometimes I'm working in an environment where I don't have much control over the availability of helpful programs so many of us take for granted.

I've been using Git Bash on Windows, and I've been getting tired of hunting down my build terminal, pressing up in my last history to get to the build command, and hitting enter to build my project. I want it to automatically run when I save a new change. But I don't have `entr` or any of the other usual suspects (like `inotifywait`) to assist me.

So to overcome this problem, with a bit of Internet searching to assist, I wrote a Bash function to watch the `src/` directory and build the project when anything in the directory changes (including timestamps, because `-l`):

```bsh
monitor_and_build () {
  local sauce=$(ls -l $1)
  while [ true ] ;
  do
    sleep 1
    local newsauce=$(ls -l $1)
    if [[ "$sauce" != "$newsauce" ]]; then
      make
    fi
    local sauce="$newsauce"
  done
}
```

to be invoked:

```bsh
$ monitor_and_build src/
```

I have a working directory `Makefile` that calls `make -C src/`.

Since I did it in such an ad-hoc way, I'm sure I missed a trick or there's some edge cases this has a problem with. Please review!

Bonus question: aside from the obvious "writing your own programs in Bash is error-prone and foolish" (I admit it took me a few drafts to get it working) - suppose I had `entr` available, and then what are the benefits of using a program like `entr` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to get false positives by comparing the output of `ls -l`.  In many locales, this command gives date stamps in different formats for newer files (day+time) and older files (year+day).  When any file transitions from "new" to "old" in this scheme, you'll get a spurious notification.  If you have the GNU implementation of `ls`, you can make it use a specific timestamp format (e.g. `--time-style=full-iso`) which might alleviate that problem.  Or just accept the false positives (`make` should be reasonably quick if nothing actually changed).

The usual problem of failing to quote arguments (`$1` where you should have written `"$1"`) will mess up arguments that contain whitespace or shell pattern characters.  Although that might be unlikely for your source directories, it's trivial to fix, and a good habit to have.

Testing that the string `true` is non-empty (`[ true ]`) is an unusual approach to making an infinite loop - most shell programmers would simply use the `true` command.  Actually, it's probably better to test the result of `sleep`, which returns non-zero if interrupted.

Instead of polling, you should be able to block on filesystem notification events.  Perhaps `inotifywait` meets your needs here?

If we use plain `[` rather than `[[`, the code becomes portable (POSIX) shell, without needing Bash extensions, so is useful to more people.

Is it right that you want to run `make` in the current directory?  For some users, it might make more sense to `make -C "$1"`.  You could be more flexible by allowing a command to be specified (here I've kept `make` as default):

```
monitor_and_build()
{
    local d=${1:-.}; shift
    test -d "$d" || return 1
    local sauce=$(ls -l --time-style=full-iso "$d")
    while sleep 1
    do
        local newsauce=$(ls -l --time-style=full-iso "$d")
        if [ "$sauce" != "$newsauce" ]
        then "${@:-make}"
        fi
        local sauce="$newsauce"
    done
}
```

Comment: Ah, I'd not come across `entr` before, so didn't realise that `inotifywait` was similar.  Thanks for the clarification.  If you have the GNU version of `ls`, you can specify the timestamp format to use - that's probably useful for this.

Comment: Already edited (I think it's a shame that SE doesn't notify the asker when answers get edited!)  Yes, `--full-time` would be a good choice (and equivalent to what I suggested).

Comment: The `-l` also becomes redundant when specifying `--full-time`, (but not for `--time-style`). Maybe we should just have `--full-time` in the code.